# Why does PostgreSQL want max_wal_senders equal to 0 and greater than 0 at the same time?

Tags: postgresql, write-ahead-logging, archive-log

We're running a backup process based on `pg_basebackup` of a Postgres 14.5 database that creates a lot of WAL archive files and using up huge amounts of disk space. As we don't really need the WAL archive, I thought to disable WAL archiving and I changed these values (everything else is pure default):

```
archive_mode = off     # was 'on' before
wal_level = minimal    # was 'replica' before (there's only a single db instance running)
max_wal_senders = 0    # was '10' before (but wal_level = minimal seems to require '0')
```

Maybe there's no real need to lower the `wal_level` from `replica` to `minimal`, but the [WAL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html) states what seems exactly sufficient for my less than critical database:

> `minimal` removes all logging except the information required to recover from a crash or immediate shutdown.

Unfortunately, after the above configuration, the backup process now fails with this error:

```
FATAL:  number of requested standby connections exceeds max_wal_senders (currently 0)
```

In other words, `max_wal_senders` must be zero and also greater than zero at the same time! What can I do to get out of this deadlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do to get out of this deadlock?

Don't set `wal_level = minimal`, don't set `max_wal_senders = 0`, and leave `wal_level = replica`. `pg_basebackup` uses the built-in replication mechanism to perform a consistent backup while the server is running (and potentially modifying data).

> The backup is made over a regular PostgreSQL connection that uses the replication protocol. [...] The server must also be configured with `max_wal_senders` set high enough to provide at least one walsender for the backup

Comment: Does that imply that even though I have a single DB in a single Postgres instance, somehow replication is used to make the backup? I thought replication is used between multiple servers...

Comment: Replication _protocol_ is used by `pg_basebackup`, as the documentation quote shows. What implements this protocol on the server side is the WAL sender.